# remove extra space in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to remove the extra space between the top and bottom images. my code is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>home</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">



    <div class="col-md-3 post-col">

            <img src="home-1.jpg" alt="" class="post-image"/>
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h5>2 days ago by Admin</h5>
            <h4>Post title</h4>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 post-col">

        <img src="home-1.jpg" alt="" class="post-image"/>
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h5>2 days ago by Admin</h5>
            <h4>Post title</h4>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 post-col">

        <img src="home-1.jpg" alt="" class="post-image"/>
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h5>2 days ago by Admin</h5>
            <h4>Post title</h4>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 post-col">

        <img src="home-1.jpg" alt="" class="post-image"/>
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h5>2 days ago by Admin</h5>
            <h4>Post title</h4>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 post-col">

        <img src="home-1.jpg" alt="" class="post-image"/>
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h5>2 days ago by Admin</h5>
            <h4>Post title</h4>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 post-col">

        <img src="home-1.jpg" alt="" class="post-image"/>
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h5>2 days ago by Admin</h5>
            <h4>Post title</h4>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 post-col">

        <img src="home-1.jpg" alt="" class="post-image"/>
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <h5>2 days ago by Admin</h5>
            <h4>Post title</h4>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
            <p>Post description here Post description herePost description herePost description
                herePost description herePost description here</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

after running the code the result look like ..
[image]

**Problem i am facing!**

As the above picture there is a large gap between the top row 3rd image and below the third image, but i want that the image is below the other image, no extra space is reserved.

the [Link](http://bbvaopen4u.com/en/actualidad) show a sample example what i want.....

Comment: Use masonry.js http://masonry.desandro.com/ or css3 columns such as: http://www.bootply.com/118335.  You can use the LESS mixins to generate the vendor prefixes for css3 columns as described here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less-mixins-vendor under the heading Columns.

Answer (score -1):

Using masonry will solve the issue.